# Services from Bluetooth Low Energy not found (Delphi + Android)

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I installed on Android and ran the Bluetooth Low Energy application from Delphi examples (Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Bluetooth\BLEScanner). The BLE devices are found correctly, but the services aren't shown. In Windows 10 works fine, that is, it finds the devices and services, but on Android doesn't display the services.

Is there some additional setting to work on Android?
NOTE: I am using Delphi 10.2.2 Tokyo.

Comment: You need to set the Bluetooth and Bluetooth admin permissions to checked in Project Options, Uses Permissions

Comment: Yes. I did it in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Device services were not being shown because there was probably a conflict between installations of other test apps that I used on the same smartphone (Android). I uninstalled everything and installed it again. It works fine.